# Change the number of plugins counted on wp-admin/plugins.php

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, pagination

I have successfully hidden my plugin from the plugins page using `$wp_list_table` however the pagination at the top still lists plugins as 'All (3)'  etc.

I managed to successfully alter the `$wp_list_table` array of `_pagination_args = total_items`.

But it was still rendering Plugins - 'All (3)'  at the top of the page.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

I have found `WP_Plugins_List_Table::prepare_items()`
has a global `$totals` variable but I am unsure of how I would change this,

Inside this function it has

```
$totals = array();
foreach ( $plugins as $type => $list )
    $totals[ $type ] = count( $list );
```

All I am looking for is to get the total plugins number and - 1 before it renders on the page.

Comment: If you want a plugin that doesn't appear in the main plugins list and can't be turned off, you should create a ['must-use' plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_plugins_list_table/

This is the class I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jacob. I wasn't aware of MU plugins.

Although I am building a plugin that does require a handful of users to be able to see the plugin and disable it in a normal manner. I have already built this functionality and got it working to hide the plugin from the plugin table for specific users, it is just the number of plugins counted at top eg 'All (3) Active (2)" that is left to change. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The values haven't any hook to change this. However it is easy to identify the counter via Javascript. You can change this with short lines of Javascript.

### Hook

You should hook in this page hook of the plugin page `admin_footer-plugins.php`, like `add_action( 'admin_footer-plugins.php', [ $this, 'change_view_values' ], 11 );`

### Function include javascript

As example a function below that change counter for the `must-use` count, but you should only change the selector for the plugin counter. Small hint, the php variable `$this->mustuse_total` is my store for the new count. You should replace this with your count, a function that get the count of plugins.

```
/**
 * Change total count for must use values
 *
 * @since   01/09/2014
 * @return  void
 */
public function change_view_values() {

    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( null === $current_screen || 'plugins-network' !== $current_screen->id ) {
        return;
    }

    $item = sprintf( _n( 'item', 'items', $this->mustuse_total ), number_format_i18n( $this->mustuse_total ) ); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
            let text,
                value,
                mustuse,
                selector;
            // replace the brackets and set int value
            selector = '.mustuse span';
            text = $( selector ).text();
            value = text.replace( '(', '' );
            value = parseInt( value.replace( ')', '' ) );
            // replace and add strings
            mustuse = value + <?php echo $this->mustuse_total; ?>;
            $( selector ).replaceWith( '(' + mustuse + ')' );
            mustuse = mustuse + ' <?php echo esc_attr( $item ); ?>';
            if ( document.URL.search( /plugin_status=mustuse/ ) !== - 1 ) {
                $( '.tablenav .displaying-num' ).replaceWith( mustuse );
            }
        } );
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

The code is currently in usage in this [mu-plugin loader](https://github.com/bueltge/must-use-loader/) - https://github.com/bueltge/must-use-loader/blob/master/must_use_loader.php#L290

### Sreenshot say more

In my context I change the must use counter, easier to understand via the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Just add -1 to count( $list ) on third line like below:

```
$totals = array();
foreach ( $plugins as $type => $list )
    $totals[ $type ] = count( $list )-1;
```